# Capturing insert, update, delete operations on every table and logging in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a SQL Server 2008 database. I need to capture Insert/Update/Delete operations on every table in the DB, take the affected primary key and insert into another table `ChangeLog`. `ChangeLog` needs capture the PK, source table, operation type.

I don't want to write triggers for every table. Whats the simplest way to do it?

Use case : I connect to SQL Server from Solr. The change log is used for delta import.

Comment: SQL Server triggers **are** a **per table** thing - there's no *database-wide* trigger. If you want to have triggers on **all tables** - you need to write a trigger for each table

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by taking a look at SQL Server Change Tracking and see whether it'll do what you need.  It's built in and simple enough to access: 
[Change Tracking Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: Does it record timestamps ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to write a trigger for every table because you think it is hard.

1. Query for a list of each table
2. Query for each table's primary key
3. Create a trigger script for add, update and delete to write to the ChangeLog table using the data for each table and primary key.

It's really not that hard to build this script and apply it to your database. If you can write it for one table, you can automatically build scripts for each table.  With an error check (does trigger exist), you can run this as new tables are added.